# How can I add CososDenshion to my ARC enabled iPhone app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I want to use CocosDenshion with my ARC enabled project but when I simply dragged the folder over, the game threw me a multitude of ARC errors. Reading the docs it seems that 1.0 was not compatible with ARC so I downloaded 2.0 beta which apparently is. But no dice.
After further reading, I gather I need it to be a static library. Lots of information pointing to this. Trouble is I don't know how to do this. :(

Can someone tell me in simple terms (or point me at a link) how to add CocosDenshion to an already existing (ARC and OpenGL using) iPhone app.

Cheers,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to deal with this few weeks ago until I found this [great article](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/) which suggests using cross project referencing to make cocos2D compatible with ARC . Hope it helps

Here is an excerpt from it...

No ARC for Cocos2D

Unless you want to completely rewrite Cocos2D from the ground up to be ARC-compatible, you’re going to have to disable ARC for the Cocos2D source code. If you’re using one of the Cocos2D templates or have simply dragged the source code into your Xcode project, you’ll need to disable ARC for each of the .m Cocos2D source files by setting the compiler flags for each Cocos2D source file.

But there’s an easier way, and it uses something called cross-project references. For Cocos2D, this is actually quite simple to set up. In your Cocos2D source folder, you’ll find an Xcode project called cocos2d-ios.xcodeproj. Simply drag this into your Xcode project, and it’ll show up as a project within your project. You can then go into your project Build Phases settings and add the Cocos2D libs to the Link Binary With Libraries build phase.

Comment: In the end I just turned off ARC for the 'm' files in Denshion as there are only 4 of them. My steps were: 1. Drag CocosDenshion folder into project. 2. Sett -fno-objc-arc flags for the denshion files. (TARGETS>BuildPhases) 3. Add the necessary Frameworks to the project: AudioToolbox, AVFoundation, OpenAL (in Build Phases again). Works great!